# Right click acts like left click on my Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: touchpad, synaptics, 18.04, dell-vostro, click-packages

After I upgraded from 17.10, right click behaves like left click.

I'm using Dell Vostro 14.

It's always getting this error when I install Ubuntu starting from 16.04 yesterday, the error is still the same... touchpad and click.

Here's the output when I type `xinput` in my terminal

```
$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate           id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID events                          id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: Same problem on my asus box after upgrading to 18.04. Trying to figure out how to resolve..

Comment: Check 'System Settings > Mouse & Trackpad > Primary button > ' whether it is set as you would expect: Left or Right.

Comment: See if these are helpful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029444/right-click-not-working-on-ubuntu-18-04 https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028776/no-secondary-button-right-click-on-touchpad

Comment: @pomsky already try, but still doesn't work

Comment: I was checking for any issues by live-booting Ubuntu 18.04 on my Asus laptop. The secondary click button on the touchpad is not working. I always have to tap with two fingers to emulate secondary click functionality.

Comment: @Shubham is that work? may I can try...

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered the same problem after upgrading from 16.04 to 18.04. I figured out that there was something wrong with settings.

[image: Mouse & Touchpad settings]

Just change primary button to left.

Comment: It's good that you posted this in the answer instead of the section because it is an answer. :-)

Comment: My right click still act like a left click.

Comment: @Hugolpz try these fixes https://askubuntu.com/a/989150/415337