# Right click on touchpad not responding 18.04lts

Tags: upgrade, mouse, touchpad

Recently I upgraded to 18.04 LTS and found that the secondary key (right click key) of the touchpad isn't responding, but while using external mouse all things seems fine.

I tried disabling two finger from Gnome tweak tool even tried adding

```
Option "ClickPad"         "true"
Option "EmulateMidButtonTime" "0"
```

to `70-synaptics.conf`, but it still did not work. I also tried setting mouse emulator to area through tweak tool.

Comment: Check these: 1. https://askubuntu.com/q/1029668/442336 2. https://askubuntu.com/q/1029444/442336 3. https://askubuntu.com/q/1028776/442336

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Right Click not working on ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029444/right-click-not-working-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No secondary button (right click) on touchpad](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028776/no-secondary-button-right-click-on-touchpad)