# Mouse frequently does effect of right click when I do single left click on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: 20.04, mouse

On

- Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, my
- Logitech B100 mouse

is frequently but not consistently doing the effect of a single right click (brings menu up) when I do a single left click.

I only want to do right click when I do right click.

This is on a simple USB-connected Logitech mouse, not anything wireless or otherwise fancy.

Is there any way to stop this behavior?  I'm pretty sure it's not a problem with the mouse itself.

**Note:**  This solution doesn't work, because I don't have a touchpad.  I just have a mouse, on a desktop full-sized case PC with a Gigabyte Z390 AORUS Master motherboard.

Comment: version of Ubuntu? Please [edit] your question with further details

Comment: Would check if you are resting right button finger on it.  Think some mice might be too touchy feely.

Comment: It's a hard plastic shell mouse and needs a press to elicit the click.  If and only if I click, do I get the right click behavior sometimes when pressing left button.

Comment: Have wireless mouse of hard plastic also by logitech.  Sometimes resting finger presses down a tiny bit, but not clicking.  Left click might be picking a bit of right button.  It could be something else, but find if I think about removing the resting finger it does not do it.

Comment: Can look at this link and see if you can use it.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/517091/sometimes-left-mouse-button-acting-like-right-and-coursor-moving-without-input?rq=1

Comment: No touchpad, psmouse not running.

Comment: Can also take it apart and see if cleaning it would help.  check for pinched wires also

Comment: Actually swapping out the mouse seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that swapping out the old mouse for a new one actually worked.  I didn't think it would because the old mouse looked fine.